# Find a function that gives this sequence: $+1,+1,-1,+1,+1,-1,-1,+1,+1,+1,-1,-1,+1,-1,-1,...$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

I start with a string $S_1=1$

then the $(n+1)$-th string is $S_{n+1}=\{ S_n,+1 ,-(S_n)\}$

if $S_j=\{s_1,s_2,s_3,..., s_i\}$

then $-(S_j)$ is defined as $-(S_j)=\{-(s_i), -(s_{i-1}),..., -(s_3), -(s_2), -(s_1) \}$

> The sequence is 
>   $[(+1_1,+1_2,-1_3),+1_4,(+1_5,-1_6,-1_7)],+1_8,[(+1_9,+1_{10},-1_{11}),-1_{12},(+1_{13},-1_{14},-1_{15})],...$

I can't find it on internet.

The properties that I noticed are these:

if $\beta(n)=\beta_n$ is the $n$-th number of the sequence we have that

- $\beta(2^n -1)=\beta(M_n)=-1$ where $M_n$ is the $n$-th Mesenenne number
- $\beta(2^n)=+1$
- $\beta(2^n +1)=+1$
- if $2^n \lt j \lt 2^{n+1}$ then $\beta_j=-\beta(2^{n+1}-j)=-\beta(2^n+2^{n+1}-j)$
- and $\forall m\in \Bbb N$

  $\beta(2^m+n2^{m+1})= \begin{cases}
   +1,  & \text{if $n$ is even} \\
   -1, & \text{if $n$ is odd }  \\ \end{cases}$

***Questions***

> 1 - There is a general formula? Have it a name?
>
> 2 - Is this sequence (and the forumula) usefull in any fields of
>   mathematics?

**Edit**: I made a mistake writing the sequence, now is fixed, and I added how I build the sequence the sequece:

Comment: does it repeat after very 6th

Comment: I'm confused---What is the definition of the sequence?

Comment: Have you tried it at [OEIS](http://oeis.org)?? Try it ;-)

Comment: @Babaka.S. Sorry, I forgot the existence of that, but now that I tried it, I can't understand nothing :S, but i think i something related with the jacobi symbol, but I can't understand it :S.

Comment: @Maesumi yea you are right, I forgot to write how I made the sequence, now is edited.

Comment: even after the edit, the description and given sequence do not seem to match. the recursive definition and the second sequence each specify something different.

Comment: @Measumi, yes you are still right. I don't know where I have the head now :S

Comment: I found your latest sequence at OEIS! It's A034947, as I just now added to my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume the sequence is $a_n$ with first six terms beginning with $a_1$ being $1,1,-1,1,-1,-1$, and also $a_{n+6}=a_n.$ Note that the nonzero squares mod $7$ are $1,2,4$, and that this is precisely where in the first six terms we have $a_n=1$.

Based on that we can come up with a formula for $a_n$ in two stages. First, define
$$f(n) = mod(\ [\ mod(n-1,6)+1\ ]^3, \ 7),$$
and note that the sequence $f(1),f(2),...$ is $1,1,6,1,6,6,1,1,6,1,6,6,...$ and repeats mod 6. (The inner mod 6 serves to place $n$ into one of the positions 1 through 6, and the outer mod of the cube mode 7 is from Gauss' lemma that the quadratic character of $a$ mod p is congruent to $a^{(p-1)/2}$ mod p. Since I'm assuming the mod function outputs the least nonnegatative residue, the sequence of $f(n)$ does what is required.

In order to get rid of the 6's and convert them to $-1$, we may finally define
$$a_n=(-1)^{1+f(n)}.$$

ADDED: The OP has now given a different definition of the desired sequence, so the above doesn't match it now. I'll try for a formula for that...

NOTE: Yet another adjustment has been made to the definition.
Here's what I think is happening with the new sequence. The condition that $S_{n+1}=S_n,1,-(S_n)$ where (this is the latest adjustment) $(-S_n)$ is obtained from $S_n$ by reversing its order and changing the signs, may be reformulated by saying that $a(2^n)=1$, (this is where the central 1's wind up), and that, for $1 \le k \le 2^n-1$ we have $a(2^n+k)=-a(2^n-k)$. That may lead to a formula...

EUREKA The sequence is $(-1/n)$ and is the Jacobi or Kronecker symbol. It is in OEIS as sequence number A034947, and at that page is the same method of generation you give, along with the fact that it is a multiplicative function and other information. For example $a(2n)=a(n)$ and $a(4n+1)=1,\ a(4n+3)=-1$. I think the page more than covers formulas for the $n$th term etc.

**Computational note:**
The computation of $a(n)$ can be done in two steps. First express $n=2^k \cdot u$ where $u$ is odd. (This expression is unique.). Then 
$$a(n)=(-1)^{(u-1)/2}.$$
To put this last another way, if $u=1 \mod 4$ return $+1$, else return $-1$.

Just for fun: Let $lg(x)=\ln(x)/\ln(2)$, the log base 2. Then let $g(x)=ceiling(lg(x)),$ and define $$r(n)=\frac{n}{\gcd(2^{g(n)},n)}.$$
Then $r(n)$ is the $r$ used in the computation of $a(n)=(-1)^{(r-1)/2}.$

Comment: I'm very sorry! but I made an error in my question, now is edited, thanks.

Comment: Thanks, anyways the question is still the same, but i just writed wrong the $5$-th term, and improved the description.

Comment: As Maesumi noticed, the recursive definition do not create the sequence, re edited it. A thing I noticed that does not change is that the lenght of the $n$-th string is a mersenne number

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to accept you answer, but can you give me more info about it? Because first I dont understand if the notation is of the Kronecker sybol is $(a|n)$ or $\({ a\over {n}} \)$ I'm a bit confused, and then what is the closed form?

Comment: The notation for Kronecker symbol is either of the notations you mention in your comment, and there is a simple way to express the sequence which does not require knowing anything about the Kronecker symbol, but whose proof uses its properties. I'll include details in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

$\Large{T(n)=(-1)^{\lceil\{\log_2((n-1)\!\!\! \mod\!\! 6\;+\;1)\}\rceil}}$

where $n\in\mathbb N, T(n)$ is the $n$th term, $\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part of $x$, and $\lceil x\rceil$ denotes the smallest integer greater than or equal to $x$.

Comment: I'm very sorry! but I made an error in my question, now is edited, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is a formula for $\beta_n$ (can be proved using induction) which explains the properties you noticed:

$$
\beta_n=
\begin{cases}
\ \ 1 \ \ \  , \text{ if } \operatorname{od}(n)\equiv 1 \pmod 4 \\
\\
-1 \ \ , \text{ if } \operatorname{od}(n)\equiv -1 \pmod 4
\end{cases}
$$
where $\operatorname{od}(n)$ is the odd part of $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: 
I understood the recursion after the edits of OP

$S_1=1, S_{n+1}=\{S_n,1,-S_n\}$ would seem to generate

$\{1\},\{1,1,-1\},\{1,1,1,-1;1;1,-1,-1,-1\}$

I hope I am right now!

Older comment:
$S_1=1, S_{n+1}=\{S_n,1,-S_n\}$ would seem to generate

$\{1\},\{1,1,-1\},\{1,1,1,-1;1;-1,-1,-1,1\}$

Comment: fixed the recursive definiton.

Comment: How about defining $S_1={1,1,-1}$  so the start of of sequence matches the title. or start with $S_0={1}$ or ...

Comment: This doesn't seem to match the recursion.

Comment: @robjohn I am recursively understanding the questions!